# Recursion with map function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree, graph-theory

I have a map like this, which represents a graph:

```
Map(5) {
  1 => [ 2, 3 ],
  2 => [ 7, 8, 10 ],
  3 => [ 4 ],
  10 => [ 12 ],
  4 => [ 11 ]
}
```

And I have this class, which creates a rooted tree:

```
class RootedTree {
    constructor (data, ...descendants) {
      this.data = data;
      this.descendants = descendants;
    }
}
```

My goal is: given a root, I want to convert that graph to a rooted tree. For the example above, using 1 as root, I want the following return:

```
const RT = (...args) => new RootedTree(...args) // just to simplify 
// goal return:
RT(1, RT(2, RT(7), RT(8), RT(10, RT(12))), RT(3, RT(4, RT(11)), RT(5))
```

Here's my code:

```
let local_descendants = []
const toRT  = (root, node_map) => {
    rt = new RootedTree(root)
    if (node_map.get(root) !== undefined){
        node_map.get(root).map((node) => toRT(node, node_map), local_descendants)
    } else {
        return null
    }

    return local_descendants
}

rt = new RootedTree(1, toRT(1, map))
```

I'm receiving an empty array from the toRT function. I guess I probably messed up with the variables, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ajax's answer is fine, but you mentioned that you had a Map, and wanted that Map instance to be an argument to `toRT` (good!).

So then the code is:

```js
class RootedTree {
    constructor (data, ...descendants) {
        this.data = data;
        this.descendants = descendants;
    }
}

const toRT = (data, map) =>
    new RootedTree(data, ...map.get(data)?.map(child => toRT(child, map))??[]);

const map = new Map([[1,[2,3]],[2,[7,8,10]],[3,[4]],[10,[12]],[4,[11]]]);
const root = toRT(1, map);
console.log(root);
```

## Explanation

From your question it is clear you are comfortable with Map and spread syntax, so let's focus on this expression:

```
map.get(data)?.map(child => toRT(child, map))??[]
```

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), i.e. `?.`, will ensure that `.map()` is only called when `map.get(data)` is defined. Otherwise `undefined` will be used instead of the `.map()` result.

`.map()` will iterate the child values found in the Map entry for `data` and translate each of them by a call to `toRT(child, map)`. The latter will return a `RootedTree` instance, so the `.map()` call will return an array of such instances, and they will serve as `descendants` for the node we are constructing for `data`.

Finally, the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), i.e. `??`, will translate the `undefined` value (that came from `map.get()`) to an empty array. This way the spread operator will work correctly also in that case.

So the deeper nodes are created first, providing the `descendants` arguments for the outer `new RootedTree` calls. The root node is the last one created.

Comment: Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

At each recursive call, you can return an instance of `RootedTree` with the `root` parameter as the `data` and the subsequent recursive calls as the `descendants`:

```
var m = {1:[ 2, 3 ], 2:[ 7, 8, 10 ], 3:[ 4 ], 10:[ 12 ], 4:[ 11 ]}
class RootedTree {
   constructor (data, ...descendants) {
     this.data = data;
     this.descendants = descendants;
   }
   display(){
      return this.descendants.length === 0 ? `RT(${this.data})` : `RT(${this.data}, ${this.descendants.map(x => x.display()).join(', ')})`
   }
}
function toRT(root = 1){
   return (new RootedTree(root, ...(root in m ? m[root] : []).map(toRT)))
}
console.log(toRT().display())
```

Output:

```
RT(1, RT(2, RT(7), RT(8), RT(10, RT(12))), RT(3, RT(4, RT(11))))
```